# Understanding the Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst command

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this code in MS access and it goes like this:

```
Private Sub List131_Click()
    Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "[iUserID] = " & Me![List131]
    Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
```

I think I understand it somewhat. The database is making a copy of itself and it is trying to find the iUserID that might match it?

However why does the list get appended at the end?

The code also used **Me.Username** in other circumstances how would that be described? Is it the copied version of the username?

Comment: `"[iUserID] = " & Me![List131]` is the search filter. Nothing is being appended. `Me.Username` is most likely a textbox named that and bound to the field `Username`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking the operations of the Sub into their component parts, we have the following:

- [`Me`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword) is a keyword that refers to an instance of the class in which the current code is executing. For example, in MS Access, if you use `Me` within a Form Module, it will return an instance of the active Form; if you use it within a Report Module, it will return an instance of the active Report.
- [`Me.RecordsetClone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.recordsetclone) returns a copy of the Recordset of the active form, such that you can perform operations on a copy of the data without impacting the live data displayed by the form.
- [`FindFirst "[iUserID] = " & Me![List131]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-findfirst-method-dao) as the method name implies, finds the first record in a Recordset which meets the given criteria.

  In this case, the criteria is constructed by concatenating the literal string `"[iUserID] = "` with the value of the form control `List131`. This might yield a string such as:

  ```
  "[iUserID] = 12345"
  ```

  Which is saying: *"Find the first record in a copy of the form data whose `iUserID` field is equal to `12345`"*
- [`Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-bookmark-property-dao) A bookmark is a way of uniquely identifying a record in a Recordset, so that you can reliably navigate to such record without knowledge of the primary key or other data held by the Recordset.

  In this expression, the bookmark of the "live" form data is being set to the bookmark returned by the cloned data, that is, the position of the record found by the `FindFirst` method.